# installation old version of scikitlearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

how i can install old version of scikit-learn ?

i need use boston house price data set and this data set didnt work on new version of scilitlearn

beacuse this message:

```
load_boston` has been removed from scikit-learn since version 1.2.
```

The Boston housing prices dataset has an ethical problem: as
investigated in [1], the authors of this dataset engineered a
non-invertible variable "B" assuming that racial self-segregation had a
positive impact on house prices [2]. Furthermore the goal of the
research that led to the creation of this dataset was to study the
impact of air quality but it did not give adequate demonstration of the
validity of this assumption.

The scikit-learn maintainers therefore strongly discourage the use of
this dataset unless the purpose of the code is to study and educate
about ethical issues in data science and machine learning.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the version when you install it via managers such like pip or conda.
Below is an example using pip: you can add the --force-reinstall if a new version is already installed.

`pip install --force-reinstall "scikit-learn==1.0.2"`

For conda, you may use `conda install package=version`. If you are installing scikit-learn in the official channel then
`conda install scikit-learn=1.0.2 -c anaconda` should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help bro With your help, my problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

For installing an old version, I would recommend to use **conda**. Using pip might result in a version mismatch if you are not careful with different packages you are installing.

command:

```
conda install scikit-learn=<your_desired_version>
```

example:

```
conda install scikit-learn=0.24.1
```

if you have created your own virtual environment, and managing through a third party IDE **pycharm**, normally there is option to select specific version there.

Comment: Very useful. Thank you.